# Relative URL in the Page Manager

Tags: uri, chaos-tool-suite

This must be something simple but I cannot figure out how it should be done.

I have a page created by Page manager (and Panels) on the url `[page-path]`. I have added a custom content with an url in it: `<a href="admin/structure/taxonomy/[vocabulary]/add">Add a term</a>`.

The problem is that on the rendered page the url is transformed to contain also the path of the page itself: `[page-path]/admin/structure/taxonomy/[vocabulary]/add`.

I suppose this is how the Page manager (or Panels) works, but I can't find out how to handle this.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: It should be `href="/admin` not `href="admin`

Comment: I've tried it but with `href="/admin...` the URL is `localhost/admin...` and not `localhost/[sitename]/admin...` as it should be.

Comment: Then make it `href="/sitename/admin`. Or use [`l()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!common.inc/function/l/7) to let Drupal care.

Comment: The sitename will change so I cannot use it; that's why I use a relative path. I'll try with `l()` and hope to understand how it works :).